# PHP MySQL - where correlation clause not reading variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, where-clause, correlation

The below code I already have does exactly what I need it to do except one thing..

Where `date(d.added) = '$date'` I also need logon to equal `$date`

I've attempted adding it into the outer as well as the WHERE statement but can't seem to get it quite right

```
SELECT d.*
FROM data d
WHERE date(d.added) = '$date' AND 
      d.logon = (SELECT MIN(d2.logon) FROM data d2 WHERE d2.name = d.name);
```

Let me know if you require anymore information

edited

---

This is how it currently looks but I don't want it displaying the results unless both added and logon are the same date
[image]

`$sql = "SELECT d.*
FROM data d
WHERE date(d.added) = '$date' AND 
      d.logon = (SELECT MIN(d2.logon) FROM data d2 WHERE d2.name = d.name);";`

`$result = $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: Perhaps some sample data and the desired results would help to exemplify your problem?  It's difficult to understand what you're after.

Comment: I'll show some examples in 2mins. I'm using single quotes as its within a variable

Comment: the above code works, I want logon to = $date as well as added (added already works)

Comment: sorry was finding it hard to explain, `added` is currently getting the value of `$date` but I also want `logon` to get the value of `$date`

Comment: `added` works fine, I just want `logon` to also look at the same variable at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You Try change:

```
 '$date'
```

to

```
 "$date"
```

Comment: I've added to my post as it probably didn't make enough sense

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below format.

`$query="SELECT d.* FROM data d WHERE date(d.added) = '".$date."' AND d.logon = (SELECT MIN(d2.logon) FROM data d2 WHERE d2.name = d.name)";`

and you will execute a query using like that below format

`$result = mysql_query($query);`

Comment: sorry was finding it hard to explain, `added` is currently getting the value of `$date` but I also want `logon` to get the value of `$date`

Answer (score 0):

Managed it:

`SELECT d.*
FROM data d
WHERE date(d.added) = '$date' AND 
    d.logon = (SELECT MIN(d2.logon) FROM data d2 WHERE d2.name = d.name AND date(d2.logon) = '$date');`